# (Pattern and Matcher) not discovering all pattern matches

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have this string object which consists of tags(bounded by [$ and $]) and rest of the text. Im trying to isolate all of the tags. (Pattern-Matcher) recognize all of the tags properly, but two of them are combined into one. I dont have any idea why this is happening, probably some internal (Matcher-Pattern) bussiness.

```
String docBody = "This is sample text.\r\n[$ FOR i 1 10 1 $]\r\n This is" +
            "[$ i $]-th time this message is generated.\r\n[$END$]\r\n" +
            "[$ FOR i 0 10 2 $]\r\n sin([$= i $]^2) = [$= i i * @sin \"0.000\"" +
            " @decfmt $]" +
            "\r\n[$END$] ";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[\\$)(.)+(\\$\\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(docBody);

    while(m.find()){

        System.out.println(m.group());

            }

output:

[$ FOR i 1 10 1 $]
[$ i $]
[$END$]
[$ FOR i 0 10 2 $]
[$= i $]^2) = [$= i i * @sin "0.000" @decfmt $]
[$END$]`
```

As you can see, this part `[$= i $]^2) = [$= i i * @sin "0.000" @decfmt $]` is not split into these two tags `[$= i $]` and `[$= i i * @sin "0.000" @decfmt $]`

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use *reluctant quantifier* - `".+?"` instead of *greedy* - `".+"` :

```
"(\\[\\$).+?(\\$\\])"  // Note `?` after `.+`
```

If you use `.+`, it will match everything except the *line-terminator* till the last `$`. Note that a *dot (`.`)* matches everything except a newline. With *reluctant quantifier*, `.+?` matches only till the first `$]` it encounters.

In your given string, you got all those matches, because you had `\r\n` in between, where the `.+` stops matching. If you remove all those newlines, then you will just get a single match from 1<sup>st</sup> `[$` to the last `$]`.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to replace the dot by a negated character class, example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[\\$)([^$]++)(\\$])");
```

*(note that you don't need to escape closing square brackets)*

But perhaps are you only interested by the content of the tags:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[\\$)[^$]++(?=\\$])");
```

*In this case the content is the whole match*

Comment: -1 for [^], which a) is not valid in java and b) even if it were valid, it would not solve OP's problem, on the contrary, it'd make it worse.

Comment: @Ingo. That's absolutely valid in Java.  And returns the same result as OP want. I'm talking about the first one.

Comment: @Ingo. It is totally valid, since you place the bracket, just after the ^

Comment: It's not valid. `PatternSyntaxException: regular expression syntax: Unclosed character class near index 2` this is what I get on `Pattern.compile("[^]")`

Comment: @Ingo: You have forgotten a closing bracket.

Comment: See, this is why @RohitJain's answer is much better.

Comment: @Ingo: believe what you want.